# Adding configuration to Test plan in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

I am facing issue with preserving the outcome from my last test execution.
e.g.

1. I have a Test Plan 'Relase2.0' and the assigned configuration is 'Win 10'
2. Now I run this test plan and I could see how many have passed, failed, blocked, not run.
3. Now I go and create a new configuration and assign this Test plan to the newly added configuration.
4. Now I switch back to my previous configuration from step 1
5. When I check the outcome from the step 2 execution, I see that I have lost those and I see all those in Not Run status.

Question: How do I preserve the execution from step 2.?

Comment: Hi friend, how do you assign the new configuration to Test Plan Release 2.0 in step3? I can't reproduce same issue on my side, could you share some more details about step3.4.5?

Comment: I'm not sure how you assign the Test plan to configuration, could you share some details about that ?